# how to specify installation target for flutter install?

Tags: flutter

I have two devices as below, one is emulator, another is real handy connected to laptop
I want to install apk directly on handy without quit emulator. how to do that?

Any hints or suggestions are more than welcome!

```
CLT L29             • WCR0218A11001181 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
AOSP on IA Emulator • emulator-5554    • android-x86   • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your app on a specific device you'll need this command: `flutter run -d deviceId`. Your `deviceId` in this case is `WCR0218A11001181` so you'll run the command below

```
flutter run -d WCR0218A11001181
```